# DISCORD selfbot in JS

Tags: javascript, discord

OK so before I get 500 comments about self bots being against TOS I already know that and I am ready to accept the risk. So I have made other selfbots about 3-4 years ago before most libraries stopped supporting it and I would like to know is there a way I can make this code to accept a user token and log in?

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
   disableEveryone: true
});
const config = require("./config.json");

var prefix = config.prefix;


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  });

  client.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.author !== client.user) return;



  if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + 'bump')) {
      msg.delete()
msg.channel.send(`**hello `)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using chrome you can open up the developer tools, go to the network tab, filter by "XHR", reload the page, find the request to /api/v6/gateway or any other url under /api, then look at the headers and find the authorization header to get your token. Then, use the token as normal.

Comment: it can also be found inside localstorage, you may need to reload though

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using discord.js just do

```sh
npm i discord.js-selfbot
```

Which is just like discord.js v12 but that allows the use of selfbots.

Answer (score 1):

As with many discord.js answers, they are deprecated with version 12. Since v12 removed support for selfbots, try the npm package `discord.js-self`. It works exactly like discord.js, except it only supports logging in using a normal account's authorization token.

Answer (score 0):

Self-bots where removed in v12.

To install the latest v11 release, use the following command:

```sh
yarn add discord.js@11
```

The problem with using other packages is that typings may not be available, while they work when using the official package.